# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now Windows won't boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

My laptop came pre-installed with Windows 8.1.

I set up dual boot. All seemed fine and I accessed Ubuntu with no issues after selecting it from the menu to select the OS. I should add that the boot method was changed to legacy.

However, since using Ubuntu, I no longer have the ability to select the OS. The laptop simply boots straight into Ubuntu.

I therefore attempted to access the recovery options, only it appears the Windows 8 bootloader has somehow been corrupted as I am now told to use the Windows 8 recovery disc (which, as this was pre-installed - I do not have).

I have tried boot repair again without success. On rebooting I am only presented with a basic splash screen asking me to select Ubuntu, Memtest, Windows 8 Recovery or Windows 8 Bootloader (The bootloaders again require I insert the disc).

I have tried

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
df -h    
sudo fdisk -l    
cat /proc/partitions


# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt9'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
set gfxmode=800x600
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=20
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=20
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro  vga=789 quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-29-generic-advanced-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro  vga=789 quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-29-generic-recovery-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro recovery nomodeset  vga=789 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro  vga=789 quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro recovery nomodeset  vga=789 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-7A6A69D66A698FA5' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7A6A69D66A698FA5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7A6A69D66A698FA5
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-8C88-80F7' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  8C88-80F7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8C88-80F7
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt9'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
set gfxmode=800x600
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=20
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=20
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro  vga=789 quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-29-generic-advanced-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro  vga=789 quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-29-generic-recovery-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-29-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro recovery nomodeset  vga=789 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-advanced-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro  vga=789 quiet quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-24-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-24-generic-recovery-d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt9'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad ro recovery nomodeset  vga=789 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt9'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt9 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt9 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt9  d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root d2f10f36-e3bb-4d83-a9b8-5d456fc454ad
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-7A6A69D66A698FA5' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  7A6A69D66A698FA5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7A6A69D66A698FA5
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-8C88-80F7' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  8C88-80F7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8C88-80F7
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

john@john-SVE1713Y1EB:~$ ^C
john@john-SVE1713Y1EB:~$ ^C
john@john-SVE1713Y1EB:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9        84G  7.1G   73G   9% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           794M  1.4M  793M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G   80K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdc1       7.5G  2.2G  5.4G  29% /media/john/DYLANMUSIC
/dev/sr0        964M  964M     0 100% /media/john/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS amd64
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  892G  972G  48% /media/john/Storage Main

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4e2ccf75

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 8011 MB, 8011120640 bytes
41 heads, 41 sectors/track, 9307 cylinders, total 15646720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            8064    15646719     7819328    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc7d968ff

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              64  3907029119  1953514528    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1     266240 sda1
   8        2    1509376 sda2
   8        3     266240 sda3
   8        4     131072 sda4
   8        5  841012780 sda5
   8        6     358400 sda6
   8        7   35376128 sda7
   8        8       1024 sda8
   8        9   89501696 sda9
   8       10    8337408 sda10
  11        0     987136 sr0
   8       32    7823360 sdc
   8       33    7819328 sdc1
   8       16 1953514584 sdb
   8       17 1953514528 sdb1
```

I did not do anything manually - the installer did everything (with the exception of changing the boot to Legacy to allow the booting of another bootloader).

Comment: Windows 8 only boots when UEFI/EFI mode is enabled, so if you want to dual boot you will have to enable that and reinstall Ubuntu. You could have saved yourself a lot of trouble by searching this site first (big search text-input field on top right next to help) for [dual booting with windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=dual+boot+with+windows+8). You'll find at least a dozen different scenarios.

Comment: You said you are using another bootloader? Windows 8 won't boot EFI mode from an MBR bootloader, but it will boot BIOS (legacy mode) from a MBR bootloader, However this is set at install time by Windows 8 (chooses which firmware to use). What was your boot set up before? For a detailed explanation [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Windows_and_Arch_Dual_Boot#Windows_UEFI_vs_BIOS_limitations) is a good link

Comment: Following advice from the site (as this was the first install I've done of Ubuntu) as a dual boot with Win8.1, I altered the boot to Legacy mode. Ububtu appeared to work however I was not presented with an OS options screen during boot.

Comment: Following advice from the site (as this was the first install I've done of Ubuntu) as a dual boot with Win8.1, I altered the boot to Legacy mode. Ububtu appeared to work however I was not presented with an OS options screen during boot. Following other advice I have seen on the site from people with similar issues, I actually got boot manager working, and made the adjustments exactly as stated, and reboot with no errors seen. (CONT.)

Comment: (CONT.)However, I now have a Grub Recover screen and absolutely no way of accessing the BIOS. Additionally, Linux.mod is not found. I am now at a dead end and cannot seem to get out of this. I cannot enter BIOS despite variations of F2,F8,F10,F12,DEL,ESC. I have a Sony Vaio laptop and the other online suggestions also come to a dead end. Beginning to regret my decision on installing Ubuntu, but hoping this is a one-off really.

Answer (score 1):

My windows system will not boot in the legacy mode at all - I believe you will need to turn the UEFI back on to make windows 8 run.  If possible, there is sometimes a UEFI / no secure boot option which works best for me.

Instead of working with GRUB directly I use `grub-customizer` which handles most anything that I have needed to do, and since it does this in a nice easy graphical interface, it's my preferred option.  One thing that it does is scan the HDD to look for alternate OS's to put into the boot menus.  You can find the instructions for getting this program [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134)

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVED**

Guess whatever happened had somehow corrupted the files and even though the Live CD and USB worked on other computers, this laptop refused to even acknowledge the disc and USB were inserted, which resulted in me coming up against the infernal Grub Recover.

Fortunately I was using a Sony Vaio which has this awesome ASSIST button. To use this, turn the laptop off completely, then instead of pressing the power button, simply press the ASSIST button. This forces open the Sony Recovery Console.

From here, it's possible to recover OS, Check and repair HDD and also access the BIOS.... so I did.

On a previous visit to the BIOS, I had changed the boot options to LEGACY in order to install another OS with Windows 8. I therefore changed this from Legacy back to UEFI and double checked the boot order. I then saved, restarted and I now have the option to select OS.